# Objective c checkbox not refreshing

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uitableview, checkbox

I have a problem with checkbox in a custom UITableViewCell.
When I touch the checkbox the image change ("checked.png"-->"unchecked.png" and "unchacked.png"-->"checked.png") and the value is saved on a DB (SQLLite).
The problem is that if I enter in a view where there is a checkbox "cheked" and I touch it, the image not change but if I reload the view, the image is correct!
How can I reload the view automatically on the event "press-checkbox"?
Here my code:

```
// called when the checkmark button is touched 
- (void)checkAction:(id)sender
{
    // note: we don't use 'sender' because this action method can be called separate from the button (i.e. from table selection)
    self.checked = !self.checked;
    UIImage *checkImage = (self.checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    [checkButton setImage:checkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Thank you vey much for any suggestion!!

Stefano

Comment: You're using self.checked, but not self.checkButton?

Comment: Sorry I haven't specified...I have a property named cheked for my class Cell: @synthesize checked, title;

Comment: Add a `NSLog(@"checked %d button %@", self.checked, [checkButton description]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)checkAction:(id)sender
{
  if(![sender isSelected])
  {
    [sender setSelected:YES];
    [checkButton setImage:[checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //Save state in Database

  }
  else
  {
    [sender setSelected:NO];
    [checkButton setImage:[checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   //Save state in Database
  }

  [YourTableView reloadData];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a change is made in an already rendered UITableViewCell, you need to reload that cell, in order to redraw it and reflect the changes.

So after you intercept the checkAction you need to reload either your whole Table (unnecessary) or simply the Table Row that has the checkbox.

I'm guessing your next question is, how do I know which row the checkbox was in ?
Well, here comes a simple but easy to implement trick.
In each of your checkboxes add a Tag value (this is an integer Value) that has the value of the row.

Then get the cell reference by:

```
- (void)checkAction:(id)sender
{
   int tag= sender.tag;
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tag inSection:0];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Now this will work OK if you only have 1 section. If you have multiple sections then it would require a bit more tweaking for getting also the table section.